# Programatically Update BitBucket Branch Permission via CLI to Automate Branch Permission Settings

Tags: bitbucket

I have several branches to update the permission settings. Is it possible to achieve this programmatically instead of manual update one by one?

Comment: Have you looked at the API documentation for this? Are you on Cloud or Server?